# Laravel + Angular JS

Tags: laravel, smarty, angularjs

Доброго времени суток, всех с наступающим.

Возможно ли заставить работать вместе Angular JS и Laravel? 
Laravel использует шаблонизатор Smarty, и есть подозрение, что синтаксис Angular JS и Smarty будут конфликтовать. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы они мирно существовали, и можно было использовать и то, и то.

Всех с наступающим, всех благ вам в наступающем 2015.

Comment: laravel + angularjs вполне нормально работают, но мне непонятно, каким боком тут smarty, ведь у laravel свой вполне нормальный шаблонизатор.

Comment: @Bastian, скорее всего, имеется ввиду конфликт переменных с двойными фигурными скобками

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть 2 решения конфликта  фигурных скобок.

1) Универсальное (подходит не только для smarty, но и для twig в Symfony2), с помощью изменения `$interpolateProvider`:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');
});
```

С этим кодом нужно будет оборачивать ангуляровские переменные в двойные квадратные скобки, например: `[[ $item.name ]]`.

2) Решение от `smarty`, тэг [`{literal}`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/language.function.literal.tpl), внутри этого тэга шаблонизатор не интерпретирует код:

```
{literal}{{ $item.name }}{/literal}
```